Azure DevOps Extension: How to validate links when a new work item is created and attached automatically?
I am developing an Azure DevOps extension to validate work item links when they are added in a work item form. I am working with on-premises Azure DevOps and using an XML process model.
The Problem:

When I add an existing work item as a link, all events like:
onFieldChanged
onSaved ...are triggered, and I can validate the link without any issues.

However, when I use the "New Item" option to create a new work item and attach it as a link:
Image reference

The new work item is created automatically.
The link is added to the parent work item.
No events (onFieldChanged, onSaved, etc.) are triggered for this operation.



Key Questions:

Is there any way to disable the "New Item" option for creating and attaching links?
How can I validate links added via the "New Item" option since events are not triggered?

Environment:

Azure DevOps Server (on-premises)
XML process model
Custom extension using Azure DevOps Extension SDK

I need a way to either:
Intercept the automatic linking behavior triggered by "New Item".
Or, validate the link after it is added to the parent work item.
Any help, suggestions, or workarounds are appreciated!
